# Getting nth user based on created_at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Original question:
Let's say I have 10 users in my database, and I want to get the 6th (or 3rd, or 8th, whatever) user based on sorted created_at date. How can I do this?

Edited question:
Let's say I have 10 users in my database, and I have a certain user, how can I determine wich nth user it is if I sort them on created_at date? (so user X is the nth user of all user based on created_at)

Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: (obviously have to change the offset value as needed)

```
User.order(:created_at).limit(1).offset(6)
```

Ok, the edited question makes this a bit more complex. Not sure if ActiveRecord is the right thing to use here. Some databases haw a kind of virtual "rownumber" which you could use for this. But lets assume we don't have that. SQL can't do that natively as such, so you could only count the number of records that are 'less' than what you look for.

Assume we have found the relevant User as `user`.

Then we could do:

```
User.where("created_at < :created_at", created_at: user.created_at).count
```

At least the best I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I realise I formulated my question wrong, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
 User.order("created_at DESC").limit(1).offset(6)
     or
 User.order("created_at DESC").limit(1).offset(6)
```

It's work like :

```
 select * from users order by created_at DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 30;
```